# Prevent multiple clicks on bootstrap modal button with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling

I use boostrap modals for saving data on an ASP.NET Web page and I'm having an issue when users by mistake clicks more than once the "Save" button on the modal. The event fires the number of times the user presses the click. This happens because the modal doesn't closes immediatly. It takes about 1 second to close, enough for the user to click more than once the button.

My database is validated (I'm using Entity Framework) so, there's no duplicate values inserted. But if the user clicks two times, it tries to insert the record two times, and the error message is displayed.

How can I prevent this?

This is the modal code:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlBank" DefaultButton="btnSaveBank">
    <div class="modal fade" id="modBank" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Banco</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBankName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" MaxLength="150"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Address</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBankAddress" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" MaxLength="150"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="row">
                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Phone</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBankPhone" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</a>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSaveBank" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnSaveBank_Click" />
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>   
</asp:Panel>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
    protected void btnSaveBank_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bank newBank = new Bank();
        newBank.Name = txtBankName.Text;
        newBank.Address = txtBankAddress.Text;
        newBank.Phone = txtBankPhone.Text;
        using (bankEntity)
        {
            try
            {
                bankEntity.Bank.Add(newBank);
                bankEntity.SaveChanges();
                lblResult.Text = "Bank successfully saved";
                ObtenerBancos();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblResult.Text = "Error when saving bank: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try disabling the save button and closing the modal via jQuery and once the modal is closed you can re-enable the save button again using jQuery. Just make sure that the jQuery event handlers are defined after `btnSaveBank_Click` so that `btnSaveBank_Click` takes precedence over the close/hide trickery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSaveBank").click(function() {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        $("#modBank").modal("hide");
    });
    $("#modBank").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
        $("#btnSaveBank").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```